# VBS - the value of variable in the for loop?

Tags: vbscript

I tried to write a vbscript to check a primary number once inputing from the inputbox like below

```
number = InputBox("How many element in the array:",1)
n = CLng(number)
redim arr(n)
' do While i < number
    ' arr(i) = CInt(InputBox("input  " & i  ))
    ' i=i+1
    ' ' wscript.echo "continue / or not (y/n)?"
    ' ' c = InputBox("Y or N ?")
    ' ' if c = "n" then
    ' ' exit Do
    ' ' end if
    ' ' if i = number - 1 Then
    ' ' exit Do
    ' ' end if  
' loop
for i = 0 to n - 1
    'wscript.echo "input " & i 
    temp = InputBox("input number " & i) 
    temp = CLng(temp)
    if IsNumeric(temp) Then
    arr(i) = temp
    end if
next
msgbox "at this time , the value of i = " & i
'msgbox "total element in array : " & UBound(arr)
for j = 0 to UBound(arr) - 1
msgbox "at this time , the value of i in the FOR LOOP = " & i
    if prime(arr(j)) Then
        wscript.echo arr(j) & " is primary number"
    Else
        wscript.echo arr(j) & " is not primary number"  
    end if
next 

Function prime(n)
    flag = 1 
    i = 2
    do while i <  n  
        if n mod i = 0 Then
            flag = 0
            exit do
        end if
        i = i + 1
    loop
    if flag = 1 Then
        prime = True
    Else    
        prime = False
    end if
end Function
```

in my code, after I use "i" as iteration to input array , then I put "i" in the FOR LOOP (using to check primary number" , what i found is the value of i was changed after each loop. So Can everyone asist me why ? please see my screenshot attached.

[image: The value of i after input array]

[image: The value of i in the FORLOOP]

[image]
[image]

Comment: It is because the same i that is used in main body is also being used in the function prime. If you declare i in the prime function (`Dim i`), it will have a scope within that function, and won't change the i in the main body. See: [VBScript Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/t7zd6etz(v=vs.84)) especially the _Scope and Lifetime of Variables_ part.

Comment: Thank you , understood :) nice weekend Bro

Comment: Hi Bro, I understood the problem , thank you

Comment: @thangvc91 In which case, close the question as a duplicate so it isn't left open.